# Make bootstrap active tab or pill clickable

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, tabs

Is there a way to make an active bootstrap tab or pill clickable? The active pill or tab by default disables the href attribute. But for my purposes i would like to keep the href attribute enabled. Is there any way to do this?

```
<div>
<ul class="nav nav-pills nav-stacked" >
        <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="someurl" >Home</a></li>
        <li role="presentation"><a href="someurl" >Profile</a></li>
</ul>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the nav-bar pill seem to be clickable in my:

### [bootply](http://www.bootply.com/QZnpg33YlB)

I think you should check your assumptions first.